# Why is the GHASH output in GCM mode encrypted to calculate the tag?

Tags: authentication, mac, authenticated-encryption, gcm

To calculate the authentication tag in the Galois/Counter mode (GCM), first a MAC is calculated using *GHASH* over the cipher text and the additional data. After that, this MAC is encrypted using *GCTR* (using the first counter).

My question is: Why is this last encryption step neccesary? What would the security problem be, if I just used the output of *GHASH* directly as the authentication tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What would the security problem be, if I just used the output of GHASH directly as the authentication tag?

Then someone listening into encrypted messages could recover $H$, one of which is correct.

The output of GHASH is a public polynomial (based on the ciphertext and the AAD), evaluated at a secret value $H$.  It turns out that, given such a polynomial, $H$ can be efficiently recovered, either by rewriting the polynomial as $\mathrm{GHASH}(H) + \mathrm{Tag} = 0$, and recovering the roots of that (which can be done in a finite field), or even easier, getting two such ciphertexts, rewriting both of them, and use an Extended Euclidean value to recover their common root.

Given $H$, an attacker can trivially make arbitrary modifications to encrypted messages; yes, that's bad.

Comment: One further question: Why is it necessary to use GCTR to encrypt the GHASH block instead of just using $Enc_H(GHASH)$ as the tag? That way, GMAC could be used without the need for an IV.

Comment: @mat: you mean sending $GHASH$ through AES (using $H$ as a key)?  Well, actually, that sort of thing would work (well, I wouldn't use $H$ as a key, but other than that...) and would be a more conservative design; however GCM was originally designed to be a pipe-lineable mode; that is, it could be implemented given an AES hardware implementation where every clock cycle, we give the next plaintext block to the hardware, and every clock cycle, the ciphertext from 10-14 cycles ago pops out.  By doing an encryption on the GHASH, we'd block the pipeline...

Comment: I just mean a simple ECB encryption (using either $H$ or $K$ as the key) of the GHASH instead of doing it with GCTR. That would have the advantage, that GMAC would be easier to use, because it wouldn't need a nonce anymore. The pipelinig is not a problem here, since the encryption of the tag is the very last step beeing done in GCM anyway, so the pipeline is definitely empty at this stage.

Comment: @mat: with pipelining, it most certainly is a problem; the message is being transmitted as it leaves the pipeline; unless we arrange things so that the GHASH value leaves the pipeline the cycle after the ciphertext block, we have a problem.

Comment: I still don't get what you mean. The pipelined computation of the ciphertext and the GHASH is not altered in any way by my suggestion. The encryption of the GHASH of value to create tag, be it with GCTR or with ECB, can only be done at the very end, when all data has already been processed. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @mat: you might be under the impression that, in a pipelined implementation, you can hold the encrypted message in memory until the pipeline is finished generating the authentication tag.  That's not the case; we are expected to transmit it immediately (that is, as the blocks are leaving the pipeline).

Comment: I know, but I do not need any ciphertext in order to encrypt the tag, do I? I can only encrypt the tag after the whole encrypted message has been stored or sent out anyway.

Comment: if we're encrypting it, why use GHASH with a key H then? Why not an unkeyed hash?

Comment: @David天宇Wong: mostly performance (GHASH is parallizable, unkeyed hashes typically aren't)

Comment: looks like if it was unkeyed, you could recompute it yourself and XOR it with the authentication tag, and then XOR the authentication tag again with a hash of your own ciphertext

Comment: @David天宇Wong: oh, right, that too...

Comment: do you know why AES-GCM uses two different key for AES and for GMAC? I noticed that if you use nonce=0, then you end up using the same key for GMAC `H=E(k,0)` and to encrypt GMAC `E(k, 0) XOR GMAC(stuff)`